# How to extend django auth user page in the admin site

Tags: django, django-admin

I know how to extend the change_form.html for my app's models. For instance, I have an app called 'sales' - to modify the admin change form I have a template in

```
[PROJECTDIR]/templates/admin/sales/customer/change_form.html
```

and I do what I need overriding the various blocks as necessary. This works well.

What I can't figure out, however, is how to modify the admin page for User objects in the same way. I've tried a variety of directory naming structures but none work:

```
[PROJECTDIR]/templates/admin/auth/user/change_form.html
[PROJECTDIR]/templates/admin/contrib/auth/user/change_form.html
[PROJECTDIR]/templates/admin/django/contrib/auth/user/change_form.html
[PROJECTDIR]/templates/admin/django.contrib.auth/user/change_form.html
```

I'm likely missing something really simple, but I can't find any docs and my Google-fu is failing to find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check what is going on in ModelAdmin.render_change_form method:
https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L1034
You are interested in value of "app_label" variable. In my env it is "auth". So your first option works ok - `templates/admin/auth/user/change_form.html`

Comment: Thanks, you got me down the right path. I'm using guardian to protect the admin views, and it changes the view specifier. Once I figured that out I got it going.

Comment: I am glad that it helped :)